# How to calculate the number of the same values in a column in a complex query?

Tags: mysql

How to calculate the number of the same values in a column in a complex query?

I use this command:

```
SELECT 
Table,id,first,second,third,code
FROM (
SELECT 't1' AS 'Table',id, first, second, third, code FROM x_table1
UNION ALL
SELECT 't2' AS 'Table',id,first,second,third,code FROM x_table2
) tbl
GROUP BY id, first, second, third, code 
HAVING count(*) = 1
ORDER BY id
```

The result of the query:

```
     id
t1 | 10 | something1 | something | something1 | something 
t2 | 10 | something1 | something | something2 | something
t1 | 33 | something3 | something | something  | something
```

As a result, I get the number of the records in the column. Now I would need to add a column where I would have the same IDs.

Example, I want first column:

```
count   id
2     | t1 | 10 | something1 | something | something1 | something 
2     | t2 | 10 | something1 | something | something2 | something
1     | t1 | 33 | something3 | something | something  | something
```

Could you give me an advice please? Thank you very much.

Comment: Just add `, COUNT(*)` to the outermost select statement (if I understand correctly)

Comment: When I add COUNT, I get 1 on all rows ... That's not it ...

Comment: And what does my query do: Query shows different lines from two databases.

Answer (score 0):

Right solution:

```
SELECT 
(
SELECT COUNT(id_zaznam) FROM 
(
    SELECT * FROM x_table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM x_table2
) temp WHERE temp.id_zaznam = tbl.id_zaznam
) AS 'pocet',
Tabulka,id_zaznam,prvni,druhy,treti,kod
FROM (
SELECT 't1' AS 'Tabulka',id_zaznam, prvni, druhy, treti, kod FROM x_table1
UNION ALL
SELECT 't2' AS 'Tabulka',id_zaznam,prvni,druhy,treti,kod FROM x_table2
) tbl
GROUP BY id_zaznam, prvni, druhy, treti, kod
HAVING count(*) = 1
ORDER BY id_zaznam
```